# Java Generic Type with extends and T using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, generics

I have a simple interface like this.

```
public interface EntityClass
{    
    public void setId(final Integer id);    
    public Integer getId();    
}
```

and a class

```
public Student implements EntityClass
```

I am trying to code a class which uses a generic type `T` but still is a instanceof `EntityClass` `a EntityClass subclass`  something like this.

```
public abstract class CustomizableQueriesForClazzAndFields<T extends EntityClass>
```

That's is the project inside that class i want a method like this.

```
public List<T>getMultipleClazzWithFields(final String ...fields){return of(genericType).retrieve(fields);}

private MyCriteria of(final Class<? extends EntityClass>applyToClazz){........}
```

MyCriteria is a wrapper over org.hibernate.Criteria.

And in my implementation would do something like this.

```
public final class TestCustom extends CustomizableQueriesForClazzAndFields<Student>
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
       final TestCustom clazz = new TestCustom();
       final List<Student>a=clazz.getMultipleClazzWithFields("id","name","phone");
       a.stream().forEach(clazz::consumer);
   }     
 }
```

Doing this code i would like to be represent it like this using generics.

```
public List<Student>getMultipleClazzWithFields(final String ...fields){return of(Student.class).retrieve(fields);}
```

But i dont know how to represent this or if it's possible.

```
public List<T>getMultipleClazzWithFields(final String ...fields){return of(genericType).retrieve(fields);}
```

Which genericType should be represent it as `Student` the same `Student` as

```
public final class TestCustom extends CustomizableQueriesForClazzAndFields<Student>
```

Or represent it as

```
public final class TestCustom extends CustomizableQueriesForClazzAndFields<School>
```

And would do something like

```
public List<School>getMultipleClazzWithFields(final String ...fields){return of(School.class).retrieve(fields);}
```

Because i was diving like this

```
public List<T>getMultipleClazzWithFields(final String ...fields){return of(T).retrieve(fields);}
```

But the compiler kicks me and says.

```
cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable T
location: class CustomizableQueriesForClazzAndFields<T>
where T is a type-variable:
T extends EntityClass declared in class CustomizableQueriesForClazzAndFields
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)
```

I also try

```
public abstract class CustomizableQueriesForClazzAndFields<Class<T extends EntityClass>>
```

But says.

```
> expected
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)
```

Or how i can accomplish my desire code.. any workaorund.

Because i a kind annoying passing as parameter.

**UPDATE**

All i wanna to do is pass a SubClass of `EntityClass` and creates.

```
session.createCriteria(genericType);
```

As well gives me the List but i dont know if it's possible to catch or capture the generic type pass `CustomizableQueriesForClazzAndFields<Student>` and passed to `of()` method which is who created the `org.hibernate.Criteria object` i cannot pass only a `T` value because in my graph would like to be a subclass of `EntityClass` a not just a `raw T value.`

I need to catch or capture

```
CustomizableQueriesForClazzAndFields<Student>
```

`Student generic type.`

If this possible or i am dreaming sorry by my poor english.

Thank a lot and best regards from Venezuela..

Comment: i'm not quite sure if i get where your problem lies, but why do you use `Class<? extends EntityClass>` instead of just simply using T? Would it be possible to give more than just the onliners as examples for what you are aiming for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1:**

I'm not sure I fully understand your question but I have the feeling you want something like this:

```
public abstract class CustomizableQueriesForClazzAndFields<T extends EntityClass> {
  public List<T> getMultipleClazzWithFields(final Class<T> clazz, final String ...fields){
    return of(clazz).retrieve(fields);
  }

  private MyCriteria of(final Class<T> applyToClazz) {
     ...
  }
}
```

The compiler can't create/retrieve an instance of `T` at runtime just from inferred data, hence you have to pass that information somehow e.g. as a parameter:

```
List<Student> l = getMultipleClazzWithFields(Student.class, "field1", "field2");
```

**Approach 2:**

Instead of passing `Class<T>` as a parameter you could also create subclasses for every `T`, e.g. `class StudentQueries extends CustomizableQueriesForClazzAndFields<Student>`, and then use reflection to find out the type of `T`. Please note though, that this would only work for sublcasses that define the concrete type of `T`.

Which approach is better depends on your needs but if it's just for that query I'd pass the class of the entity as a call parameter and skip all those subclasses that would be needed otherwise.

**Update**: if you want to implement the second approach (subclasses) have a look here for some code on how to use reflection to look up the type of `T`: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208860

Comment: I was able to get the generic type. like this.     private final Class<? extends EntityClass>clazzToBeApplied;
    public CustomizableQueriesForClazzAndFields(){clazzToBeApplied=(Class<? extends EntityClass>)((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];return;}    
put it on your answer and i will mark it as resolved..

Comment: I follow your link post and i solved using this. retrieving the generic class using. `clazzToBeApplied=(Class<? extends EntityClass>)((java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];`